# How to extract tweets between two dates using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've a code used to extract tweets based on location and keywords using a developer account. I'm able to receive tweets real time but I'm looking to extract tweets between two dates. I've read articles that the max we would be able to go back in history would be 2 weeks back from current day. So I'm using below code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = '#####'
consumer_secret = '######'
access_token = '#####'
access_token_secret = '#######'
startDate = datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0)
endDate =   datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0)

file_exists = os.path.isfile('searchtweets.csv')

with io.open('searchtweets2.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Text', 'Username', 'User', 'User_location', 'User_coordinates']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if not file_exists:
                writer.writeheader()


class listener(StreamListener):
        def on_data(self, data):
                all_data = json.loads(data)

                # collect all desired data fields
                if 'text' in all_data:
                        tweet          = str(all_data["text"]).encode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
                        username       = str(all_data["user"]["screen_name"]).encode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
                        user           = str(all_data["user"]["id"]).encode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
                        user_location  = str(all_data["user"]["location"]).encode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
                        user_coordinates   = str(all_data["coordinates"]).encode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
                        #print(str(all_data).encode("utf-8", errors='ignore'))
                        print(tweet)
                        with io.open('searchtweets2.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
                                fieldnames = ['Text', 'Username', 'User', 'User_location', 'User_coordinates']
                                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
 #                               if "alaska".encode("utf-8", errors='ignore') in user_location:
                                writer.writerow({'Text': tweet, 'User': user, 'Username': username,
                                                 'User_location': user_location, 'User_coordinates': user_coordinates})

                        return(True)
                def on_error(self, status):
                        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["flowers","choclate"],languages = ["en"], locations = "-122,36,-121,37", since=startDate, until=endDate ,
                     stall_warnings = True)
```

When I run the above code I'm receiving error saying unexpected keywoed argument 'since'. 
I'm new to python please help me place the parameters at the right place in the code to let it run.

Thank you.